# How can an element of a string array be used as a variable of another string array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

for example i have following code

```
String[]    subject  =  new String[6];
subject[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter subject");
String[] subject[1]=new String[6];
```

it will not work.There is any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

*You cant do that*, unless you declare the first array as 2 dimensional

```
String[][] subject = new String[6][];

subject[1] = new String[6];
```

Comment: it is not the case.actually I want to create a new array, whose variable name is the element of subject array

Comment: *You cant do that* , thats the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] target = new String[VALUE_DESIRED][];
target[i] = new String[VALUE_DESIRED];
```

VALUE_DESIRED is a integer value which you prefer
i should less than VALUE_DESIRED

Answer (score 0):

This code also works,

```
    String[][]    subject  =  new String[6][];
subject[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter subject");
subject[1]=new String[6];
```

altenatively, you can use the concatination operator for adding multiple strings to the value of sub array of type String,

```
 subject[1]=subject[1]+"first"+"second"+"third";
```

Comment: String[] subject={"java","php","C#","C++"}; now i want to crate arrays like String[] java; String[] php;.. if these elements (java,php,c++)enterd in run time. how it is used as a variable to create a new array

Comment: use the concatination operator(+).